# How to start using EntityFramework 4.1 (or 4.3 currently)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, objectcontext

1. I've installed EntityFramework through nuget (**should I do this for every project?** Or can I just reference the assemblies? **Where are they 'installed'**? Sorry new to nuget)
2. I add a new "Ado.NET Entity Data Model" to my project and import tables from the database. **However the context is added as `ObjectContext` not as the latest `DbContext` as I would presume. Am I missing something here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, install the package for each project. The assemblies are installed in a packages folder in the solution folder.
2. The ADO.NET Entity Data Model is for Database First.  Read an explanation of Database First vs. Model First vs. Code First here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I'm working database first, does this mean I cannot generate an DbContext object and work with EntityFramework 4.1 and up?

Comment: It looks like I need a Entity Data Model (edmx) file open in the designer. From there I need to "Add an item" and select "DbContext generator". What's up with this 'connection' between the two? DbContext cannot live without ObjectContext and related entities?

Comment: If you want to use the DbContext without an .edmx, you can use the EF Power Tools, which is only in CTP now:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start is http://asp.net. Read the tutorials. They cover data access with EF for both [WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/working-with-data-%28entity-framework-tutorial%29) and [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).